# Android Application Builder No Coding

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

i would love to know is there is any drag and drop (no coding) dynamic android application builder who also generate android studio native source code with it.

`Hello World!`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out https://bubble.is/ It lets you build apps without coding, from what I understand.

Comment: i know bubble and many app builder who build apps without coding but my question is that any builder "Generate Android Studio Source Code".

Answer (score 0):

[MIT's AppInventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/) is an innovative beginner's introduction to programming and app creation that transforms the complex language of text-based coding into visual, drag-and-drop building blocks.

The simple graphical interface grants even an inexperienced novice the ability to create a basic, fully functional app within an hour or less.

Comment: My friend i am searching app builder who generate "Android Studio Source code". i am looking for app builder who export project source for android studio.